# React undefined error when looping over a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run a loop over a collections and a build a component like: `<my_div> things.map((value, index) => myComponent<value={value}> </my_div>`

I'm getting an error saying `that "value" is undefined`

Comment: Can't tell without seeing what is in `things`, but did you check to see if there were any `undefined` in that array?

Comment: elaborate your code more.

Comment: What is the content of things?

Answer (score 1):

Is that your exact syntax above?

If it is you need curly braces around your `things.map`

```js
<my_div>
  {
    things.map((value, index) => <MyComponent value={value} />
  }
</my_div>
```